# Run PHP script in HTML5 app over server?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, html

I'm currently working on an HTML5 app that runs jQuery Mobile. My app, designed in the IntelXDK needs to communicate with a server MySQL database running PHP. The MySQL database stores the scores from recent high school and middle school sporting events for my local school district. I have been able to successfully write a PHP script that submits the data from an HTML form into the database, however, when I include it in my HTML app, it doesn't do anything, even when I run the PHP script that is hosted on the server. Is there any way I can get the script to run in the app, or is it easier to make the form online in the server? This needs to be secure so that only the athletic director and myself can access it. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is processed by a server and then delivered to the host making requests, thats it.  You can't really 'run' PHP in an app unless you mean making requests to a server that hosts php.  But the PHP cannot run locally.

I would look in to creating an API on the server that your app can request information from.

Edit:
Here is a simple Ajax request with jQuery

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  data: { 'id':id },
  context: document.body
}).done(function(data) {
  $( this ).html( data );
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the HTML form inside the app 'run' the PHP script from the server? Or is that not a thing?

Comment: Yes.  Say your php script on the server returns a simple list of items based on input you give it, such as an id.  The thing that takes time is forming the data that php is requesting in to something you can return to your app.  I would look in to the jQuery $ajax function to make requests to your php page.